# How to unit test a function that returns undefined

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I have a typescript function that might return undefined f.e.

```
export function selectWeapon(status : boolean, axe? : Axe, sword? : Sword) : Axe|Sword|undefined {
  return status?axe:sword;
}
```

When I am trying to unit test it I get a TSError:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

which I suppose is true and it should normally not create any concern . Is this a tsconfig file issue actually ? How can I unit test this function ?

The test code failing is :

```
it('should return an axe', async () => {
 const weapon = Weapon.selectWeapon(true, axe, sword);
 expect(weapon.type).to.equal(Weapons.AXE);
}
```

Comment: "When I am trying to unit test". Please share the test code that throws this error.

Comment: The issue is that in your test code, accessing `weapon.type` might give you an exception because `weapon` is possibly undefined.